# How do I loop through a text file and input that data into a matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix, text-files

[MATLAB]

I have a text file that is a list of numbers. Below is a sample but my actual file is a list of thousands of values, each on a new line.

> 0.01080000000
>
> 0.00720000000
>
> 0.05760000000
>
> 0.00360000000

How do I loop through this text file and input the data into a matrix of the size x = 431 and y = 415? Again, text file just has a list so every 431st number I need to go to a new row in my matrix.

```
clear;

%Load in text file
filename = 'Water_1973_points.txt';
T = fopen(filename);

%Count number of points in x,y (x = 431) (y = 415)
xsize = 431;
ysize = 415;

m=zeros(xsize, ysize);
tline = fgetl(T);
for k = 1:length(T)
    for h = 1:xsize
     for j = 1:ysize
         m(h,j) =  k*255;
     end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file is that simple it's easy enough to just use [`importdata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) and [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).

For example, using the following `Water_1973_points.txt`:

```
1
2
...
10
```

And

```
m = importdata('Water_1973_points.txt');
m = reshape(m, 5, 2).';  % Transpose because MATLAB is column-major
```

Returns:

```
m =

     1     2     3     4     5
     6     7     8     9    10
```